# Finding $\cos(A+B)$ from $\sin(A+B)$

Tags: trigonometry

The question states to start with the identity: $$ \sin(A+B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)$$ It then asks to use the above to prove that: $$\cos(A+B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$$

All I can think of is to say $\cos(A+B)=\sin(\pi/2-(A+B))$ but expanding that doesn't lead me to the answer and I can't think of anything else so help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: HINT: $\pi/2-(A+B)=(\pi/2-A)+(-B)$

Comment: Hint: it depends how you're expanding it. Since, from looking at the identity you want, it looks like you want to replace $\sin(A)$ by $\pm\cos(A)$ in the identity you have, try splitting $(\pi/2-A-B)$ into two parts in such a way that applying the first identity will achieve this.

Comment: Got it now thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat $A$ as a variable, and keep $B$ as a constant and differentiate:

$$\cos(A+B) = \frac{d}{dA}(\sin(A+B))=\frac{d}{dA}(\sin A \cos B +\cos A \sin B ) = \cos A \cos B-\sin A\sin B.$$

This is assuming that you have already covered differentiation of trigonometric functions.

Edit:

Clearly, this approach is only sensible if you have obtained the derivatives of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ by means of their definitions via power series, or some other method which avoids the necessity of knowing the expansions for $\sin(A+B)$ and $\cos(A+B)$.

When I was a student, I found this method a useful way for quickly deriving formulae that I didn't wish to memorise ...

Comment: Agreed that this is an alternate way to avoid memorizing one extra formula - a method that I am also using. The question is what happens when both A and B are varying simultaneously? see also problem # 498798.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that

$$\cos(A+B)=\sin(\pi/2-(A+B))=\sin(\pi/2+(-(A+B)))$$

and then use the sine addition formula given to you with the two terms being $\pi/2$ and $-(A+B)$. You will also have to use the parity of the trig functions to pull out that minus sign at the end.