# Finding cos(A + B) from sin(A + B) --- a sequel

Tags: trigonometry

Given : $\sin(A+B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)$

To prove: $\cos(A+B) = \cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$

[The original question, which was posted as problem # 498742, has been solved.]

I am wondering is the following argument valid?

By treating $A$ as constant, differentiating $sin (A + B)$ w.r.t. $B$, I got the required.

Similarly, by treating $B$ as constant, do the same thing to $A$, I also got the required.

Hence, I conclude that $\cos(A+B) = \cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$

Comment: Differentiation works, provided that you can justify that the derivative of $\sin t$ is $\cos t$, etc.  However, to prove those derivative formulas, you have to look at the difference quotient, which requires using the angle addition formulas that you're trying to prove!  **Beware of circular reasoning!**

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498742/finding-cosab-from-sinab

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of *etymology*.  The prefix *co-* in *cosine* refers to *complementary*.  Specifically, the *cosine* of an angle $t$ is the *sine* of the *complement* of $t$, i.e. $\tfrac{\pi}{2} - t$.

$$
\cos t = \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - t \right)
$$

If you think in terms of complements, any formula about the *cosine* function is just a similar formula about the *sine* function.

Also, note that the calculation
$$
\frac{\pi}{2} - \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - t \right) = t
$$
shows that the *complement of the complement of an angle* is just the angle itself, or in other words, the *cocosine* is just the *sine*.  So, the formula

$$
\sin t = \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - t \right)
$$

is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just replace A by $\frac{\pi}{2}+A$ and use $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+A) = -\cos(A)$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+A) = \sin(A)$?

In order to derive the formula's for the derivatives you'll need these, so taking a derivative won't work to get your result.

I was almost going to say that you can do it via the imaginary exponents, but also these require the above definitions.

Comment: Differentiating requires knowing both addition formulas, unless the functions are defined by their Taylor expansion.

Comment: @egreg differentiating would give the solution if you know the derivatives and apply the chain-rule. Or am I mistaken ?

Comment: How do you *compute* those derivatives? See Sammy Black's comment above.

Comment: Referring to the above answers, perhaps I did not make myself very clear. First, when I temporary treat A as constant and let B varies, I got the required. Next, when I temporary treat B as constant and let A varies, I also got the required. Then, can I conclude that the goal is attained when both A and B vary?

Comment: @egreg of course, if you can't take an infinitesimal step then you can't do the derivative (consider my comment edited). For Mick, the point that they are trying to make is that when you vary you make your value A and/or B increase so you need these sum-formula's! So yes indeed the derivative is not a good way to prove these formulas since you use them to construct your derivative!

Answer (score 0):

This is a great way to derive those identities.  It works especially well if you first define $\sin$ and $\cos$ as power series, or in terms of the integral $\int_0^x\frac1{1+t^2}dt:=\tan^{-1}(x)$.  If you define them using circles or triangles, though, then you end up using those identities in order to find the derivatives that you used, as Sammy said in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

since $$\sin^2(A+B)+\cos^2(A+B)=1$$

$$\sin(A+B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B)$$

$$(\sin(A)\cos(B)+\cos(A)\sin(B))^2+\cos^2(A+B)=1$$

$$\sin^2(A)\cos^2(B)+\cos^2(A)\sin^2(B)+2\sin(A)\cos(B)\cos(A)\sin(B)+\cos^2(A+B)=1$$

$$(1-\cos^2(A))\cos^2(B)+(1-\sin^2(A))\sin^2(B)+2\sin(A)\cos(B)\cos(A)\sin(B)+\cos^2(A+B)=1$$

$$\cos^2(B)-\cos^2(A)\cos^2(B)+\sin^2(B)-\sin^2(A)\sin^2(B)+2\sin(A)\cos(B)\cos(A)\sin(B)+\cos^2(A+B)=1$$

$$\cos^2(B)+\sin^2(B)-\cos^2(A)\cos^2(B)-\sin^2(A)\sin^2(B)+2\sin(A)\cos(B)\cos(A)\sin(B)+\cos^2(A+B)=1$$

$$1-\cos^2(A)\cos^2(B)-\sin^2(A)\sin^2(B)+2\sin(A)\cos(B)\cos(A)\sin(B)+\cos^2(A+B)=1$$

$$\cos^2(A+B)=\cos^2(A)\cos^2(B)+\sin^2(A)\sin^2(B)-2\sin(A)\cos(B)\cos(A)\sin(B)$$

$$\cos^2(A+B)=(\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B))^2$$

when $B=0$

$$\cos(A+B)=\cos(A)\cos(0)=\cos(A)$$

Thus

$$\cos(A+B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to show all this in one go is to use rotational matrices. $$\bf{R}_\phi = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi)\\-\sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi) \end{array}\right)$$ We know that accumulated rotation adds the angles rotated. Therefore the composite rotation: $${\bf R}_{\phi+\theta} = {\bf R}_\phi {\bf R}_\theta$$
Now performing this matrix product and looking at the resulting elements (1,1) and (1,2) gives us the laws of addition of both sines and cosines.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I have no question about the validity (or the derivations by yours or others) of the formula. Starting from the formula $\sin (A+B) = \sin (A) \cos (B) + \ cos (A) \sin (B)$, I used a ***curious*** method to obtain the corresponding formula, namely $\cos (A+B) = \cos (A) \cos (B) − \sin (A) \sin (B)$. My question is “Are there any way to justify my approach (i.e. 1st, when I temporary treat A as constant and let B varies, after differentiation, I got the required. Next, when I temporary treat B as constant and let A varies, I also got the required.) in such derivation?”

Comment: If the differentials are the same everywhere, the only thing which can differ are constants or mean values.

Comment: Could you elaborate in greater detail?

Comment: Any addition rule must be symmetric because addition is commutative so you would only need to treat it as function of one variable. if f' = g' everywhere for two functions f and g, they can still differ by a constant, since the constant function is what is lost when doing differentiation.

Comment: Thank U 4 the explanation..